# can you write xml file in html file

Tags: javascript, html, xml

This may sound too stupid but I have been going crazy for finding that out. I just need to know how to write `XML in HTML` file so I can send it using `Ajax`.

I know how to send `XML` using `XMLHttpRequest` after I have included external file but that is not what I am trying to do here. My XML file is really small like 3 tags. So I don't want to write external file for no reason. Please explain despite being good with Javascript,CSS, and HTML. I have very limited experince with XML. Mostly because I love JSON over all other methods...

Comment: Write `XML` in a `HTML` File?

Comment: You can definitely do it with Javacsript forming XML and posting it in using Ajax

Comment: @MackieeE as i understand i have to send xml using ajax..what is the best way to do it. I think if i could just like write it and then send it would be nice :D

Comment: How would you solve it with a small piece of JSON? And how is XML different?

Comment: Javascript - > http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3337/XML-and-JavaScript

Comment: guys don't close this i am totally clueless about xml...and it's not my choice i am trying to learn ebay api which accepts xml data.

Comment: As far as i understood this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest should be close to what you are looking for. Your question would be better if it would include what you have tried and where you are stuck. If your question is specific to ebay why not point to the documentation and show your code?

Comment: that link shows how to send data as parameters with ajax post..what i want to know is how to send xml data with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
function element(name,content){

    var xml
    if (!content){
        xml='<' + name + '/>'
    }
    else {
        xml='<'+ name + '>' + content + '</' + name + '>'
    }
    return xml
}
```

Call this function from a HTML page